# Should I flag comments as no longer needed for fulfilled requests?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I noticed there is a flag *No longer needed*

[image]

Should comments that request something like:

> please provide the blend file

be removed after they have been fulfilled with a comment like:

> i have added blend file to my post

? Should both of these comments be flagged as *No longer needed* to weed out comments noise?

In addition I'd like to know if the *No longer needed* flag punishes the commenter? Because it shouldn't right? As the comment has just gotten outdated.

It would be nice though if these comments were removed by the persons commenting since both comments cancel each other out and only make the comments list too long if they remain.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I would prefer it that way. Unfortunately, these users usually don't add their blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/, but via other cloud services and then add this link as a comment. What should happen with it then?

Comment: Yes please flag them, those are usually irrelevant in the long run. Flagging one comment per post is enough. As far as I know it does not penalize the user in any way

Comment: Would it be reasonable to delete surplus links to cloud services, on the grounds that they aren't archival, _when_ they can no longer aid answers in the short term?  Ideally the answers would not depend on the links.

Comment: Deleting outdated or broken links is ok, migrating them without user consent is not. There was a [discussion about file migration to Blend Exchange](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275) a while ago, the issue was accepting a different terms of service.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos From my point of view, file links to various clouds should be filtered anyway, because they actually always contain links to files that remain unavailable in the long run. A better guidance on how to use https://blend-exchange.com (possibly via upload icon in the RTE, as with images) would be helpful and would also eliminate any ambiguity from the beginning. Would something like this be possible?

Comment: A button in the toolbar would be the best way to ensure usage of Blend Exchange, but that is not up to us mods or even as a community, I think. I think [this has been brought up in the past](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/suggesting-adding-a-button-link-for-uploading-blend-file-above-the-text-box), but that would probably require development from the network staff, and I'm not so sure they be willing to spare the labor for supporting a service run by a third party.

Comment: From the main Meta [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work), comments are *temporary "Post-It" notes. It is more than reasonable to flag them for deletion when they do not add value.

Comment: AFAIK there is no flag that harms a user, but you should consider any follow-up action from a community mod for some flags